# Custom node.tpl.php for specific page

Tags: 7

I have a custom page template (Drupal 7) created from a basic page and I call it page--node-84.tpl.php. I'd like to manually print/render the 'body' field from this page and so I tried that doing this:

```
<?php print render($content['body']); ?>
```

But that is not working because I believe I can only print a field when using a node template and not a page. Correct?

Could someone help me with a pre-processing function to be able to print a field in a page template. Or maybe using a custom node template is the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available variables differ between the [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) versus the [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7) (see the top of each of those links for documentation of the default variables).

If the default variables in the templates don't meet your needs, you can [customize them using preprocess functions](https://drupal.org/node/223430). See the [documentation for template_preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) to get an idea of how the variables get added. NodeOne has a screencast on "[Providing new template variables](http://nodeone.se/en/providing-new-template-variables-preprocessing-1)" that might also be helpful.

Comment: I've looked into the variables for the page template and have come to the conclusion that a preprocess function is needed. I don't know much PHP so that is where I was hoping for a bit of help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dan, please see the updated answer. I've added a couple more links to details on adding variables via preprocess functions.